# React Change button color onClick realtime - dynamically change/update attribute in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, button, material-ui

I'm using firebase and react to create a realtime chat (based off of a tutorial online). i want to be able to click on any of the chat bubbles (which are actually buttons) that have already been sent and have it change color (for any user that is on the chat page).

It first prompts the user for a name and then allows you to send messages: [chat image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHtWi.png). Should I create an onClick function that somehow changes the color and then pushes that attribute to firebase? How can I go about doing this? How can I dynamically update data on firebase from my code?

This is what I have so far:

```
export default function TwoTruths() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [name, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsername(prompt("Please enter your name"));
  }, []);

  const handleSend = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    db.collection("twoTruths").add({
      message: input,
      name: name,
      image: image,
      timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    });

    setInput("");
  };
    
  
  return (
    <div className="twoTruths">
      {messages.map((message) =>
        message.name ? (
          <div className="twoTruths__message">
            <Avatar
              className="twoTruths__image"
              alt={message.name}
              src={message.image}
            />
            <button className="twoTruths__text">{message.message}</button>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div className="twoTruths__message">
            <button className="twoTruths__textUser" >{message.message}</button>
          </div>
        )
      )}

      <form className="twoTruths__input">
        <input
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          className="twoTruths__inputField"
          placeholder="Type here..."
          type="text"
        />
        <button onClick={handleSend} className="twoTruths__inputButton">
          {" "}
          SEND{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```